# Huygens' wave theory

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction, superposition, huygens-principle

The wave theory says that every point on the wavefront is taken as a source of secondary spherical wavelets. Now what I want to know is
what does this actually mean?
As every point is producing waves will they not interfere with one another? Will we be seeing an interference pattern?
I am just unable to visualize it in my mind.
Can somebody please explain it to me what the theory is all about? And do it in a simple way so that I could visualize it better.

Comment: Not sure why this question is flagged as to be closed. It is clear enough. Secondary waves are interfering with each other and they have the same phase as the original wave, so they are interfering with each other constructively, which keeps the original wavefront going. When the wave is disrupted by an object, then we think of the reflected wave as a collection of new waves that have the proper phases and we are interfering those with each other, which will form interference patterns.

Comment: Please google _geometrical envelope_.

Comment: Maybe "...explain it to me what the theory is all about?" is too broad"

Comment: see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209_Making_waves_the_geometric_derivation_of_Huygens'_Principle_for_wave_propagation_and_the_problem_of_the_wake

Answer (score 4):

Basically Huygens Principle is just a way that was envisioned in the 17th century to describe how wave behaves and is understood as in the following picture. 
Each point on the wavefront radiates spherical waves which interfere to preserve it during propagation.

[image: Hyugens Principle]

This picture is inspired from Rayleigh Scattering where the emitters are actually all the electrons of the atoms in a material which react to the electric field.

Though Huygens principle is not completely correct, in particular one needs to add an obliquity factor to prevent backward propagation.
Moreover for large wavelength on small aperture the Huygens principle is definitely no longer valid.

To sum up I would say that Huygens principle is a convenient way to describe wave propagation and particularly diffraction which happens to be adequate in many cases. However this principle is not fundamentally right.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I do think the last sentence is a bit strong, though. Huygens's principle is amazingly near to the later ideas of building solutions out of Green's functions and fundamental solutions to the D'Alembert and Helmholtz equations. It comes out, albeit as an approximation, of an analysis of the Helmholtz equation: have you seen the discussion in Chapter 8 of Born and Wolf or the appendix in Hecht and Zajac?

Comment: Yes you are right about the solutions of D'alembert. But again you recover Huygen's Fresnel principle only in the case of far field and small wavelength i.e. $\rho>>\lambda$.Otherwise you have to cope with higher order terms as in the case of a radiating antenna.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the idea in detail, but broadly speaking you take some points on the your wave, draw spherical wave maxima around the points, and then find where there is constructive interference. This will give you a set of new points that basically describe where the wave front ends up.

Of course, in nature this is supposed to happen for each of the infinite number of points on the original wave, and not just a few, but that is not possible to visualise.

Comment: Suppose i have a light bulb emitting light.now,as the light is emitted it will be travelling like a wave nd if Huygens's theory is correct every point on the wavefront is producing secondary wavelets.i am a bit confused at this point.as these secondary waves r generated they must interfere and if i put a screen i must be getting an interference pattern. But i don't think this really happens.

Comment: We are considering here the case of a big extended wave, and the points is that in this case there are an infinite number of points emitting secondary waves, and they produce a continuous series of maxima, each right next to the other, or in other words they add up to a continuous wave.

Answer (score 0):

Huygen's principle is that each point of a wavefront is the point source of secondary waveform.
Another point is,all secondary wavelets spread around in all directions with the speed of light.
Another is,if we draw a common tangent from all the spheres, we will get the resultant wavefront.

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the interference that deep joshi is confused about.